# On parsing Json object using Json::parseFromStream it gives an ordered Json::value how to get original state?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

```
    // Parse JSON and show errors if needed
Json::CharReaderBuilder rbuilder;Json::Reader reader;
Json::Value root;
// Configure the Builder, then ...
std::string errs;
std::istringstream config_doc(jsonString);

bool parsingSuccessful = Json::parseFromStream(rbuilder, config_doc, &root, &errs);
```

here we get Json::value root which gives us ordered list of the parameters how can we get the original state of params?
jsonString example= {
"_id" : 0,
"title" : "",
"author" : "",
"available" : 0,
"checkout" : ""
}

with above example when we iterate the root i get :
_id, author,available,checkout,title
which is ordered by parameter name
but i want it in the order the json object is i.e
_id,title,author,available,checkout

any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "ordered" Json::value? What is the output you get and what do you expect? Can you please edit the post and clarify this?

Comment: jsoncpp simply doesn't support this, see e.g. [here](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/1202). the json specification also doesn't--a JSON object is an _unordered_ collection of key-value pairs, so there's no obligation for a conforming parser to respect insertion order. if you need the order of elements to remain stable, consider using JSON arrays like `[{"paramName": "_id":, "paramValue": "0"}, ... ]` instead of objects